# How to fadein and fadeout a Div with a close button?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, fadein, fadeout

Hello fellow Brainiacs!

I've tried everything I possibly can. Hopefully one of the many JQuery experts out there can help me out.

Take a look at my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahsatan/yc4spxy0/5/)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="aboutbutton" class="btnblue">About</button>

<br /><br />


<div id="contentboard">
      <button type="button" id="closebutton" class="btnclose">X</button>

      <p>
          Hello World!<br />
          Hello World!<br />
          Hello World!<br />
        Hello World!
      </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#aboutbutton').on('click', function() {
    if($('#contentboard').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#contentboard').html(strAboutUs);
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').toggle();
      $('#contentboard').html(strAboutUs);
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').fadeIn(1000);
    }

  });


$('#closebutton').on('click', function() {
      $('#contentboard').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

By default, the contentboard div is visible with some content and the div contains a closebutton.
When I click the closebutton, the div fades out - perfect.
When I click the blue "about" button, I want the div to fade back in - perfect. But upon fadein, the close button does not appear.

I don't understand why this is happening. I tried using multiple selectors so that the div and the closebutton can fadein together, but that didn't work either.

How do I get the closebutton to appear and disappear with the div?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: when you replace the html , that wipes out the button ...`$('#contentboard').html(strAboutUs);`  ... new html has no button in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#closebutton` is inside your `#contentboard`, thus, it is erased when you call `$('#contentboard').html(strAboutUs);`

**Try this instead :**

Instead of calling `.html(...)` on `$('#contentboard')` I called it on `$('#contentboard>p')` so it will only replace the `<p>` content and your `#closebutton` won't disappear !

```js
var strAboutUs = "<p>Hello World!<br>" +
        "Hello World!<br>" +
        "Hello World!<br>" +
        "Hello World!<br>" +
        "Hello World!</p>";



$('#aboutbutton').on('click', function() {
    if($('#contentboard').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#contentboard>p').html(strAboutUs); // Changed
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').toggle();
      $('#contentboard>p').html(strAboutUs); // Changed
      $('#contentboard,#closebutton').fadeIn(1000);
    }

  });


$('#closebutton').on('click', function() {
      $('#contentboard').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
#contentboard {
 width:300px;
 height:auto;
 left:10;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#E0F5FF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10;
 -moz-border-radius: 10;
 border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666666;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666666;
 margin = 25px;
 padding = 25px;
}


.btnblue {
 background: #52baff;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #52baff, #2980b9);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #52baff, #2980b9);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #52baff, #2980b9);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #52baff, #2980b9);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #52baff, #2980b9);
 -webkit-border-radius: 10;
 -moz-border-radius: 10;
 border-radius: 10px;
 text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666666;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666666;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top:25px;
 margin-left:25px;
 margin-right:25px;
 width:250px;
}



.btnclose {
 background-color: #E5E5E5;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 right:1px;

 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="aboutbutton" class="btnblue">About</button>

<br><br>


<div id="contentboard">
      <button type="button" id="closebutton" class="btnclose">X</button>

      <p>
        Hello World!<br>
        Hello World!<br>
        Hello World!<br>
        Hello World!
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: to add to this, doesnt the toggle in the `else` part need to only be applied to the outer div?

Comment: It depends on your expectations. If you are satisfied with the actual result, you have no need to change it.

Comment: yea but its not doing anyting.. clean that up in your code, remove the `#closebutton` from `$('#contentboard,#closebutton')` , its not needed

Comment: Ninetainedo = Thanks a ton! I can't believe that's all it took to change the content! I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: CodeGodie = Thanks! I'll clean that up.

Comment: No problem. its always better to keep your code as clean as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
$('#contentboard').html(strAboutUs);
```

to this:

```
  $('#contentboard *').not("#closebutton").remove();
  /*this line will remove all content but not the closebutton*/

  $('#contentboard').append(strAboutUs);
  /*then you can add what you want to be the new content*/
```

It's a way... maybe it helps

Answer (score -1):

In order to hide and show the div all you is fadeIn fadeOut methods. No need for display none or having to .html the string, but if you do wanna change the content upon close or about button just html inside #contentboard p

```
$('#closebutton').click(function(){
$('#contentboard').fadeOut('normal');
});

$('#aboutbutton').click(function(){
$('#contentboard').fadeIn('normal');
});
```

Comment: no button to insert when clicking on about button. once you add button tag to var strAboutUs, you'll get a button to appear; however, the on click event $(body).on('click','element', function(){code}) for closebutton had to be changed as well so that it'd be clickable

Comment: I see what you mean now. you re-added the button that was initially deleted, but why delete it in the first place?

Comment: It wasn't my intention. I've just made the initial code provided by the person asking the question and made it work.

Comment: in my opinion the best solution for this would be just create and event with a class 
$('#aboutButton, #closeButton').click(function(){
    $('#element').toggleClass('hide');
});
and then this class would have a display none property with transition.

Comment: you should add an answer with this code. Its interesting seeing other ways to do the same. Its where performance is considered.

Comment: Will do it next time, good sir! thanks for advise! I am new to stack, I'll get used to it in due time.